# VB.NET-Column header of DataGridView when importing the DataSet

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataset

1. Insert data to DataSet..

   ```
   Dim table As New DataTable
   table.Columns.Add("Name")
   table.Columns.Add("Score")
   table.TableName = "Group1"
   dataset.Tables.Add(table)
   ```
2. Combine with datagridview

   ```
   dgv.DataSource = dataset.Tables("Group1")
   ```

   There are two different situations

   - Set the column Collection in designer
   - Didn't set anything in designer

If I set the dgv column "Name" and "Score" in designer, the outcome will be like
  Name Score Name Score
             John   100
             Jack   100
The duplicate columns appeared...

If I set nothing to the dgv, the outcome will be fine.

However, if there is no data in DataSet, the column header, "Name" and "Score", won't show up in dgv.

How do I solve this problem?
I would like to display the dataset in dgv even when the dataset has no data and the header still can be displayed.

Comment: The format of this article is awful!!!  How do I fix it?

Comment: You have to play with the [`AutoGenerateColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: After the DGV autogenerates the columns (when you set the data source), you can change the names.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]